# Casting a string containing comma separated values into an integer

Tags: python, string, list, casting, int

given a string :

```
>>> string = "0,1,2"
>>> print string
0,1,2
```

how can I split the string and cast the values into integers, putting them into a list?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, many correct answers, I'll accept the answer I consider clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mystring = "0,1,2"
mylist = [int(i) for i in mystring.split(",")]
print mylist
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `split`, `int`, and a simple list comprehension.

```
In [1]: s = "0,1,2"

In [2]: t = s.split(",")

In [3]: t
Out[3]: ['0', '1', '2']

In [4]: v = [int(u) for u in t]

In [5]: v
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2]
```

In one go:

```
In [7]: v = [int(u) for u in s.split(",")]; v
Out[7]: [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split,map and int` map produces a list by applying the given function(int as of now) on the given iterable

**Code:**

```
string = "0,1,2"
lst = string.split(",")
int_lst  = map(int, lst)
print int_lst
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to map the cast to `int` to every element of the list you create when splitting it.

```
>>> string = "0,1,2"
>>> print map(int, string.split(','))
[0, 1, 2]
```